# What's the correct way of binding to a JSF property that is expensive?

Tags: java, jsf-2

Here's my scenario:

I'm using JSF.

1. I have a page that refreshes every 5 seconds (but the user doesn't notice it because everything is ajaxified)
2. I'd like to have a modal window that shows a list of things to the user when the user clicks something (e.g., a button). So every time the user clicks that button, the modal appears with the up to date list.

Right now I have the following: the modal with the a property loaded to it. This property loads stuff from DB and returns the list to the JSF page.

The main problem is since the page refreshes every 5 seconds, this property is called every 5 seconds (i.e., a request to DB).

Summarizing: I'd like to have a modal that loads a list every time the user clicks a button, inside a page that refreshes (ajaxified) every 5 seconds.

What's the right way of doing such things? Pointers to good tutorials are good answers, I don't need code, but rather understand the best practice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd fetch the list from the database whenever the user clicks the button, and put it into a property of a bean that survives the current request (scope = session, view, conversation, or whatever), then bind that property with the EL expression.

To fetch the list upon clicking the button, have the button trigger an ajax request that rerenders the content of the panel, and makes the panel visible upon completion of the ajax request. You haven't said what ajax or component library you are using; with Richfaces, it's something like:

```
<a4j:commandButton 
    action="#{mybean.fetchListFromDatabase}" 
    rerender="panelcontent" 
    oncomplete="Richfaces.showModalPanel('thepanel')"
/>
```

Comment: RequestScope bean is not good for this kind of scenarios, remember that the RequestScope is created on every request (in this case, in every ajax call) to the server. Scope session could do the work too, but it will be preferable to use the narrow scope for the task at hand.

Comment: I know that; where in my answer do I say to use the request scope?

Comment: Thanks for the answer meriton. But how exactly do I do this in the context of a modal window?

Right now I have a form that is merely hidden by CSS, (so that form is being submitted on every page refresh). When I'm clicking the button, all it's doing is showing the form with the list.

Do I need some kind of server generated modal?

Comment: I'm using Icefaces. I'll check out how to do this with it and get back to you shortly.

Answer (score 0):

The modal panel is already implemented in RichFaces and PrimeFaces libraries

- [RichFaces 4 Popup Panel](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=popup&sample=modalPopup&skin=blueSky)
- [PrimeFaces 3 Dialog](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/dialog.jsf)

Both implementations includes ajax and jQuery to manage the basic behavior. You can use one of these to implement your modal panel and the list that recovers data from DB (using a ViewScope managed bean).

If you can't or maybe don't want to add any of these libraries into your project, you can use their code and use it as a startup for your implementation (both libraries are open source).